# Is there a way to not do a get on the entire branch (in TFS) after switching the local folder?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I want to move my code over to the D: drive and point to it in my workspace, but it always makes me perform a get. Is there a way to do this without performing a get?

Comment: Change the mapping from Visual Studio and have it handle the moving of the workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change your `Mapping Workspace` on your `source control` by editing, you can also delete and create new

[image]